# Screen sleeps and mouse and keyboard won't wake it....Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: screen

I received an old gaming computer with a A780X AMD motherboard and an HD3650 GPU. I am connecting with the VGA port on the graphics card (because the monitor only has VGA) and the screen sleeps randomly and won't wake with a mouse or keyboard.

I have checked the BIOS settings and made sure that all of the power settings etc. are as optimized as possible. I have booted the hard drive from another computer and re-installed the GPU drivers, additionally I am currently using the VGA Cable and monitor with my laptop and everything seems to work fine.

If it is not the GPU Driver, or the BIOS's settings then it has to be something in the Ubuntu 18.04 setting.

Does anyone know how to fix this? The only thing I can think of next is to flash the BIOS, but I can't seem to find the AMD BIOS flash file to put on the USB.